# pyqt4 QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName clicke cancel Button

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm using PyQt4.

```
 filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Save file", "", "CSV files (*.csv)|*.csv")
```

Now when I click cancel button,the next code is executing. But, I don't want this instead I want it to do nothing. How can I achieve this?

```
If filename is None:

stop excute code.
```

Comment: Do look for `sys.exit(value)`?

Comment: No. Just close the FileDialog Window. Background MainWindow is remained. @wp78de

Comment: If user clicked cancel button. Is there any event how can system noticed user click cancel button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user presses Cancel, `getSaveFileName` returns a null string.

You can use the fact that empty sequences are false. So, you should use:

```
if filename:
```

or

```
if not filename:
```